# xpath selector of jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, cucumber, capybara

My page has a jquery ui datepicker on an input field #graph_start_date

I'm trying to write the following Cucumber steps

```
When I click the graph start date
Then I should see a datepicker
```

Here's what I have for the step definitions:

```
When /I click the graph start date/ do
  find(".//*[@id='graph_start_date']").click
end

Then /^I should see a datepicker$/ do
  page.should have_xpath(".//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div' and ?????????]")
end
```

The jquery ui datepicker initially inserts into the dom

```
<div class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden-accessible" id="ui-datepicker-div"></div>
```

When its popped up the dom contains

```
<div class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden-accessible" id="ui-datepicker-div" style="position: absolute; top: 523px; left: 167.5px; z-index: 1;">
```

After its dismissed the dom contains

```
<div class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden-accessible" id="ui-datepicker-div" style="position: absolute; top: 523px; left: 167.5px; z-index: 1; display: none;">
```

Comment: There is no question asked. ???

Comment: i tried page.should have_xpath( "//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div' and contains(@style,'display: block')]" )  but page.body doesnt even contain the js generated code, so how do i write the assertion?

Comment: actually this also fails (would indicate the picker is or ever was popped up)   page.should have_xpath( "//div[contains(@style,'position: absolute')]" )
so maybe the click's not really working? but when i pause in the debugger i can see the datepicker in the Webdriver Firefox window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `:visible => true` option which is documented in `Capybara::Node::Matchers#has_xpath?` so:

```
Then /^I should see a datepicker$/ do
  page.should have_xpath(".//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']", :visible => true)
end
```

However, this may be a different problem but for me the datepicker does not appear at all when the capybara driven browser does not have focus, and so my test fails *(sometimes)*!

**EDIT:**

First of all it seems that the datepicker does not actually want a click on the field to trigger but a focus which unfortunately is unsupported by capybara's selenium driver and it does not trigger when you trigger a click but the browser has no focus.

The correct way to trigger the focus would be:

```
find(".//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']").trigger('focus')
```

but that raises a `Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError` :(

To workaround you can use the *hackish*:

```
When /I focus the graph start date/ do
  page.execute_script("$('#graph_start_date').focus()")
end
```

**(thanks to: http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/msg/af6caeef01d978b0)**

There are various discussions and relevant issues on this in Google Groups:

- http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/64b96cb15cda3f36
- http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/e7e88b2d8ab3b61e
- http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/ebcdad1a084f57a8
- http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=543
- http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=157

Answer (score 0):

I would just run some javascript which #focuses the field, clicks 1 of the anchors... then let capybara make sure the right value is in the field.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem this morning, and here's how I fixed it.

In my feature file

```
@javascript # You need this javascript tag 
Scenario:Adding a date to a job 
  When I go to enter a date 
  Then I should see a date picker appear
```

In my step definitions:

```
When /^ I go to enter a date$/ do 
  element = find_by_id("you_date_field_id") 
  element.click 
end

The /^I should see a date picker appear$/ do 
  date = find(:xpath, "//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']") 
end
```

Hope this helps